# django inspectdb options for DateTimeField

Tags: python, mysql, django

I use the command below to auto-generate models from my MySQL DB.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

For some tables I have *insert_time* and *update_time* fields, and after converting to models they become **DateTimeField** type, and I found both of the fields will not be updated to the database. I need to add `auto_now_add=True` for *insert_time* field and `auto_now=True` for *update_time* field manually... Is there a way to give configurations for inspectdb or any other more efficient ways to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django can't tell whether a date time field should have `auto_now_add = True` or `auto_now = True` from inspecting the database. This is the kind of thing you need to fix up yourself after running `inspectdb`.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb):

> This feature is meant as a shortcut, not as definitive model generation. After you run it, you’ll want to look over the generated models yourself to make customizations.

If you have many many fields to update, your text editor may have a feature that will let you update the fields quicker, e.g. search and replace or macros.